# Error in View Route Laravel with Virtual Host XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, virtualhost

I'm was change my XAMPP port to 8000 and I open my virtual host with http://laravel.test:8000/
I try to add this to my routes.php :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('homepage');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

but when I'm try to open : http://laravel.test/about:8000/ or http://laravel.test/homepage:8000/ it's error. 
How can I open that page with the xampp port changed?

Comment: What's the error ? plz provide the code ?

Comment: @itisallyours thats the error I cant open my php file on Laravel/resources/view with  http://laravel.test/about:8000/ or http://laravel.test/homepage:8000/. 
FYI : 
1. I have changed my xampp port to 8000
2. If I open  http://laravel.test:8000/ it will only open up 1 of my php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your routes properly

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('homepage');
});
```

http://laravel.test:8000/

```
Route::get('about', function () {
  return view('about');
});
```

http://laravel.test:8000/about